# already , southern pronunciation ≈ [ʰɑɾi] "oddy"

Tags: american-english, speech, phonology, accent, phonetics

Cut to the chase pals

Could anybody confirm the southern pronunciation of "already" as something like *oddy* ? if so, What's its phonetic transcription? is there any eye spelling for it? I've noticed Jessica Simpson in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nrjp6e04dZ8&t=1m49s) pronouncing something like "haddy or haddie", kind of [ʰɑɾi], adding even a bit of aspiration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: She's not saying "oddy" -- It's closer to "uh-red-ee.  Basically just a perfectly normal "already", only with the "I" slurred into it and pronounced fairly rapidly.

Comment: @HotLicks I do not think there's a vowel such as /ɛ/ anywhere to be found in her pronunciation, plus there appears a glottal stop in between.

Comment: Related phenomenon : https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510554/already-pronounced-as-%cb%88%c9%94%ca%8b%c9%aa