# "already" pronounced as [ˈɔʋɪ]

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonology, songs

What is the pronunciation of **already** in the song *Without Me* by Halsey?

What phonological processes take place resulting in such a pronunciation?

(min 3:03) https://youtu.be/ZAfAud_M_mg?t=183

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I don't know the song (you couldn't provide a YouTube link?), but in a general sense it's not that uncommon to hear strange pronunciations in songa.

Comment: Listening to YouTube, 80% of that song is unintelligible.

Comment: The process is called [dysarthria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysarthria).

Comment: Apparently /ʋ/ is a voiced labiodental approximant. I can't see how one of those can get into *already.* In fact, a [Google search for the lyrics](https://www.google.com/search?q=halsey+without+me&oq=halsey+without+me&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4391j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) doesn't contain the word. So it must be another word you're asking about. However, phonological processes are **more likely** to be on-topic on Linguistics.se -- [do check before asking there](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: *already* is in the lyrics (*I already know*, near the end). But it sounds to me like she's saying *I 'ready know* or *a'ready know*, leaving an entire syllable out. So presumably the flapped /d/ is what the OP is hearing as /ʋ/. It's a somewhat indistinct flapped /d/, but that's what I hear.

Comment: @GJC - You should provide a YouTube link and the time in the video where the word is spoken.

Comment: @HotLicks (min 3:03) https://youtu.be/ZAfAud_M_mg?t=183

Comment: @GJC - OK, I removed my downvote.  But music lyrics are still pretty much off-topic.

Comment: What is wrong with this question? Open it back up so I can answer it. Moderators need to stop closing English linguistics questions.

Comment: I hear /aˈʔɔːɹɾinoʊ/, which should be fairly self-explanatory. She pronounces the word _already_ quite quickly, which reduces the vowel in the second syllable to more or less nothing, but apart from that, I don’t hear anything unusual about her pronunciation there.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214656/already-southern-pronunciation-%e2%89%88-%ca%b0%c9%91%c9%bei-oddy

Answer (score 1):

It's standard.  Well, somewhat.  Because she's singing, she draws out the first syllable "all" and then says "ready" really fast on a single beat, and she admittedly is affecting her speech a little bit with a contrived accent that over-accentuates vowels by rounding them.  However, she does not do what you say she's doing.  At the precise moment of that in the song you cited, she clearly pronounces "'I 'AAAAHL-reddy NOooh," not "'I 'AW-wih NOooh," as you suggest, nor "'I 'reddy NOooh," as another suggests."

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214656/already-southern-pronunciation-%e2%89%88-%ca%b0%c9%91%c9%bei-oddy